# Bash scripting rsync puzzler

Tags: bash, rsync

Frustrating. The script below work for the first two targets, but not the second.

```
#!bin/bash
...
backitup () {
Todaysdate=`date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H_%M_%S"`
Sourcedir=$1
Destination=$2
Username=$(echo $Sourcedir | cut -f1 -d'@')
if [ "$Username" = "root" ] ; then
    RSYNCPATH="rsync"
else
    RSYNCPATH="sudo rsync"
fi

cmd="sudo rsync -vazP --rsync-path='$RSYNCPATH' --log-file=/var/log/rsync.log $Sourcedir /BACKUPS/$Destination/back-$Todaysdate"
                echo $cmd >> ~/cmd.txt
                $cmd
...
}
backitup root@HAZns01:/etc "HAZNS01/etc"
backitup root@HAZns01:/home/ftpusers "HAZNS01/ftpusers"
backitup jakadmin@HAZFAND10:/etc "HAZFAND10/etc"
backitup jakadmin@HAZFAND11:/etc "HAZFAND11/etc"
```

The second two calls give:

```
unexpected remote arg: jakadmin@HAZFAND10:/etc
```

If however I run then run the contents of cmd.txt manually from the commandline (bash cmd.txt) then it runs fine. How can that be? (I've got  passwordless ssh all setup correctly of course)

What am I missing?

Comment: Opps! Added a couple of lines to make this clearer

Answer (score 4):

Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

> This fails because of WordSplitting and because the single quotes
>   inside the variable are literal; not syntactical.

You should avoid putting commands in variables when shell scripting.

Use a function to be able to reuse a command. Use `set -x` for logging. Or use an array to hold the individual parts of the command and its arguments only if you must.

By the way, in one line you use `$()` for command substitution. This is the correct way. In another line you use backticks which is deprecated. At least be consistent.

Comment: All working now! Took out the "cmd=" stuff, replaced  '$RSYNCPATH' with "rsync" or "sudo rsync" depending on some ugly if/then/else. Nice task to refactor another day :-)